# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined in ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework

I am building an app with ionic 5, i want to show ion-loader when a user tries to login, and after a response is gotten from the server, it will dismiss the ion-loader, but when i tried it, i got this error

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'dismiss' of undefined
```

here is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home.page';
import { NavController, AlertController, LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AuthServiceService } from '../auth-service.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
    } 
  registerCredentials = { email: '', password: '' };
  loaderToShow: any;
  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    private auth: AuthServiceService,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController,
    private loadingCtrl: LoadingController
  ) {
    console.log(this.registerCredentials);
  }

  public login() {
    this.showLoading();
    this.auth.login(this.registerCredentials).subscribe(allowed => {
      if (allowed) {        
        this.loaderToShow.dismiss();
        console.log('canceal')
      } else {
        this.showError('Access Denied');
      }
    }, error => {
      this.showError(error);
    });
  }

  public async showLoading() {
    this.loaderToShow = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
        message: 'Please Wait...'
    });
    await this.loaderToShow.present();
  }


  public async showError(text) {
    this.loaderToShow.dismiss();

    let alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
        header: 'Fail',
        message: text,
      buttons: ['OK']
    });
    await alert.present();
  }

}
```

Pls how can i properly dismiss the ion-loader

Comment: Try to change your initialization in constructor from private to Public:
`public loadingCtrl: LoadingController`

Comment: i tried it but its not working

Answer (score 3):

Create a `hideLoading()` method like below can call it when you want to hide the loading circle.

```
async hideLoading() {
    this.loadingController.getTop().then(loader => {
      if (loader) {
        loader.dismiss();
      }
    });
}
```

I created below class to handle show hide of loading in my ionic application.

**loading.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoadingService {

  isLoading = false;

  constructor(public loadingController: LoadingController) { }

  async showLoading(message?: string) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.loadingController.create({
      message: message ? message : 'Please wait...'
    }).then(loader => {
      loader.present().then(() => {
        if (!this.isLoading) {
          loader.dismiss();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  async hideLoading() {
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.loadingController.getTop().then(loader => {
      if (loader) {
        loader.dismiss();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Usage in a component:

```
export class SomePage implements OnInit {

  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private loadingService: LoadingService) { }

  someMethod(updateNameForm: NgForm) {

     this.loadingService.showLoading();

     this.someService.someMethod().subscribe(response => {
         // Some code
     });

     this.subscription.add(() => {
          this.loadingService.hideLoading();
     });
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add await to the call of the function `showLoading`

```
 public login() {
        await this.showLoading();
        this.auth.login(this.registerCredentials).subscribe(allowed => {
          if (allowed) {        
            this.loaderToShow.dismiss();
            console.log('canceal')`enter code here`
          } else {`enter code here`
            this.showError('Access Denied');
          }
        }, error => {
          this.showError(error);
        });
        }

    async showLoading() {
        this.loaderToShow = await this.loadingCtrl.create({
            message: 'Please Wait...'
        });
        await this.loaderToShow.present();
    }


    async showError(text) {
    await this.loaderToShow.dismiss();

        let alert = await this.alertCtrl.create({
            header: 'Fail',
            message: text,
          buttons: ['OK']
        });
        await alert.present();
    }
```